# String split regex with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, regex

I'm needing a regular expression to separate the text when returning true in the expression. But the expression I made is not working, the text does not separate.

```
function namesNew() {
var names = "M123, M125, M125, K126, L128";
var names_new = names.split('/[M[0-9]{3}[\,]]/');
console.log(names_new);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `names.split(/\s*,\s*/)`?

Comment: Response:(5) ['M123', 'M125', 'M125', 'K126', 'L128']
0: "M123"
1: "M125"
2: "M125"
3: "K126"
4: "L128"
length: 5

Comment: What do you mean to say? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: The answer should be: M001, M002

Comment: I need to separate by elements containing M001, M002

Comment: There are no `M001` and `M002` in your string. Does `names.match(/\bM\d{3}\b/g)` solve the problem?

Comment: You should just do a match for `M00[12]` the split regex for this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.match` with

- with no `[` and `]` around the pattern so as to match a sequence of patterns
- using word boundaries to make sure the match is a whole word
- `g` flag to match all occurrences

```js
const names = "M123, M125, M125, K126, L128";
// Get all matches
console.log(names.match(/\bM\d{3}\b/g));
// Get all matches and remove duplicates
const names_new = [...new Set(names.match(/\bM\d{3}\b/g))];
console.log(names_new);
```

One more solution here is to match in between commas, whitespace or start/end of string

```js
const names = "M123, M125, M125, K126, L128";
const names_new = [...new Set(names.match(/(?<![^,\s])M\d{3}(?![^,\s])/g))];
console.log(names_new);
```